# Ansible does not create directories CentOS7

Tags: ansible, centos

This my ansible script

```
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - file:
       name: add dir
       path: /etc/ansible/roles/webservers/'{{item}}'
       state: directory
       mode: 0755
       owner: nikola
      vars:
       dir_list:
        - handlers
        - vars
        - defaults
        - meta
      with_items: ' {{ dir_list }} '
```

and this is the output from `--check` option

```
PLAY [localhost] ****************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [file] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=handlers)
ok: [localhost] => (item=vars)
ok: [localhost] => (item=defaults)
ok: [localhost] => (item=meta)

PLAY RECAP **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two mistakes:

1. `name` as parameter of `file` module. It is an alias of `path`, so you actually try to create directory `add dir`.
2. Unnecessary single quotes in `path`, giving you actual paths like `etc/ansible/roles/webservers/'handlers'`.

Try with:

```
...
- name: add dir
  file:
    path: '/etc/ansible/roles/webservers/{{ item }}'
...
```